# HTML & Event Pages: Unspecific IDs and Classes at the top

Tags: wordpress, css, html

I'll be referencing the HTML created by Wordpress, CiviCRM, and possibly the Pinboard theme.

I was looking to restyle event pages (only) and began with the page with all events: */civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&html=1*

This page, including individual events, and other public-facing pages created by CiviCRM have little to nothing in ways of identifying the page by unique IDs or descriptive Classes, especially at the very top of the parent hierarchy.

It seems that every page has the same way of identifying CiviCRM's body (For me it's the class page-id-4412), is useful to select every CiviCRM page. As we continue down, we notice there is a general but clear CiviCRM class and ID beyond the initial page's header:

```
<div id="crm-container" class="crm-container crm-public" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

There is two problems I am having with this:

1. It has nothing specific to the *type* of CiviCRM page it is. ie. is it a contribution page? Event page? etc.
2. It is well past parent elements in the page that CiviCRM is using. ie. the header: `<header class="entry-header">`

Has anyone found a way to select content using clearly marked IDs or Classes this early in the HTML?

For instance, to change the styling of the header between the Event list page and individual event pages appears to me to be impossible by css alone.

To select,
`<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title">`

This does fall under the page-id-#### ID and class, but nothing specific to the type of CiviCRM page. There would need to be something more specific in the class like,

```
<body class="crm-individual-event">
<body class="crm-event-list">
<body class="crm-individual-contribution"
```

If you know a workaround, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This can be done in Drupal's theme preprocessing, with reference both to the Drupal path (which Drupal does know about there) and relevant variables from `$_GET` (if you detect you're in a CiviCRM contribution page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `body_class` filter, query CiviCRM's state and then add suitably named classes:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_civi_add_body_classes' );

/**
 * Add classes to body element if on CiviCRM basepage.
 *
 * @param array $classes The existing body classes
 * @return array $classes The modified body classes
 */
function my_civi_add_body_classes( $classes ) {

    // bail if no CiviCRM
    if ( ! function_exists( 'civi_wp' ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    // bail if not on CiviCRM's basepage
    if ( 'basepage' != civi_wp()->civicrm_context_get() ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    // get CiviCRM's arguments
    $args = civi_wp()->get_request_args();

    // bail if we don't have any
    if ( is_null( $args['argString'] ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    // check for event
    if ( isset( $args['args'][1] ) AND $args['args'][1] == 'event' ) {
        $classes[] = 'civi-event';
    }

    // check for listing
    if ( isset( $args['args'][2] ) AND $args['args'][2] == 'ical' ) {
        $classes[] = 'civi-event-list';
    }

    // check for info page
    if ( isset( $args['args'][2] ) AND $args['args'][2] == 'info' ) {
        $classes[] = 'civi-event-info';
    }

    // check for registration
    if ( isset( $args['args'][2] ) AND $args['args'][2] == 'registration' ) {
        $classes[] = 'civi-event-registration';
    }

    // ... add further checks ...

    return $classes;

}
```

Amend as per your requirements.

Cheers, Christian

Comment: Thanks mate. I've been too busy troubleshooting a primary issue to try this out but it looks promising.

Would I include this in my theme's functions.php file?

Comment: Yes, in functions.php or a custom plugin.

Comment: It's such a sensible request that I'm going to create a PR to include this on the CiviCRM plugin itself :-)

Comment: Evan, descriptive classes for all CiviCRM pseudo-pages rendered on the WordPress basepage will be in core as of CiviCRM 4.7.18. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/111

Comment: Christian,

Thank you so much. I feel guilty not getting to play with your suggestion. Because this design edit is much less a priority for my work right now, but I do appreciate you keeping me in the loop.